# Updated bitcoin mining energy usage

Tags: client, mining-profitability

Is there an up to date and updated chart which tracks the entire energy used by bitcoin mining rigs worldwide?
Looking for the energy used per t-hash.

Comment: Have you seen https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison?

Comment: This would be a difficult statistic to obtain.  Due to the decentralized nature of mining, mining pools couldn't tell you how much electricity their pool uses.  That information is at the mining-facility level.  You could estimate based on the network hash rate, and the average hash rates of the "profitable" ASICs on the market.  However, which ASICs are profitable depends on what the local electricity and cooling costs are for owner.  You can probably roughly estimate this, but not obtain an exact figure.